# Google Oauth2 - redirect_uri_mismatch 400

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, gmail-api, google-api-python-client, google-developers-console

Hello i am trying to integrate Google Sign In into my python script and i am running this this error:

*Access blocked: This app’s request is invalid*

*You can’t sign in because this app sent an invalid request. You can try again later, or contact the developer about this issue. **Learn more about this error***

*If you are a developer of this app, see **error details**.*

*Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch*

My python script im trying to run is the basic one from Google sources:

```
# import the required libraries
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
import pickle
import os.path
import base64
import email
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Define the SCOPES. If modifying it, delete the token.pickle file.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']

def getEmails():
    # Variable creds will store the user access token.
    # If no valid token found, we will create one.
    creds = None

    # The file token.pickle contains the user access token.
    # Check if it exists
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):

        # Read the token from the file and store it in the variable creds
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)

    # If credentials are not available or are invalid, ask the user to log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

        # Save the access token in token.pickle file for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    # Connect to the Gmail API
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # request a list of all the messages
    result = service.users().messages().list(userId='me').execute()

    # We can also pass maxResults to get any number of emails. Like this:
    # result = service.users().messages().list(maxResults=200, userId='me').execute()
    messages = result.get('messages')

    # messages is a list of dictionaries where each dictionary contains a message id.

    # iterate through all the messages
    for msg in messages:
        # Get the message from its id
        txt = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=msg['id']).execute()

        # Use try-except to avoid any Errors
        try:
            # Get value of 'payload' from dictionary 'txt'
            payload = txt['payload']
            headers = payload['headers']

            # Look for Subject and Sender Email in the headers
            for d in headers:
                if d['name'] == 'Subject':
                    subject = d['value']
                if d['name'] == 'From':
                    sender = d['value']

            # The Body of the message is in Encrypted format. So, we have to decode it.
            # Get the data and decode it with base 64 decoder.
            parts = payload.get('parts')[0]
            data = parts['body']['data']
            data = data.replace("-","+").replace("_","/")
            decoded_data = base64.b64decode(data)

            # Now, the data obtained is in lxml. So, we will parse
            # it with BeautifulSoup library
            soup = BeautifulSoup(decoded_data , "lxml")
            body = soup.body()

            # Printing the subject, sender's email and message
            print("Subject: ", subject)
            print("From: ", sender)
            print("Message: ", body)
            print('\n')
        except:
            pass


getEmails()
```

I created a project in Google Console and gave it redirect uri of my http://localhost:8000/

if anyone knows how to fix it, i will be glad
thanks.

Comment: Based on current scenario following link has answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76983078/error-400-redirect-uri-mismatch-because-of-trailing-in-redirect-uri-from-goog

Answer (score 10):

The redirect uri miss match is one of the most common errors we face when starting development with Oauth2. This is actually a configuration error on your part.

There is a link on the error message where you can click `error details`.

[image]

On this page it will tell you the redirect uri that your application is sending from.

[image]

You need to take that uri and add it in Google cloud console for your project under the client.

[image]

This video will also show you how

[Google OAuth2: How the fix redirect_uri_mismatch error. Part 2 server sided web applications.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHz1Rs6lZHQ)

## Installed app vs web app

The code you have now is intended to be run as an installed application. hence the `flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(                CREDENTIALS, SCOPES)`  It opens the authorization consent screen on the machine the code is running on.  For this code to work properly you should create desktop credentials on google developer console. If you are seeing a redirect uri miss match error it is probably because you have created web app credentials instead.

This code is not meant to be run on a web server as it spawns a local web server.   `creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)`  You need different code if you intend to run this on a web server  [web server flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#python_1).

## web app sample

Im still playing with this I need to work out how to get it to refresh the access token as needed. which should be done with the following. I just need to work out how to test when it needs to be refreshed.

```
oauth2_client = oauth2.GoogleRefreshTokenClient(
    client_id, client_secret, refresh_token)
```

What I have so far:

```
import os

import flask
from flask import Flask,redirect,render_template,url_for, request
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import ssl
context = ssl.SSLContext()
context.load_cert_chain('C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Python\cert.pem', 'C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Python\key.pem')

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow

SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']

REDIRECT_URI = 'https://127.0.0.1:5000/oauth2callback'

CREDENTIALS = 'C:\Development\FreeLance\GoogleSamples\Credentials\CredWebEverything.json'

def get_flow():

    # Initialize the flow using the client ID and secret downloaded earlier.
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
        CREDENTIALS,
        scopes= SCOPES,
    )
    # Indicate where the API server will redirect the user after the user completes
    # the authorization flow. The redirect URI is required.
    flow.redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI

    return flow


def redirect_user():

    flow = get_flow()
    # Generate URL for request to Google's OAuth 2.0 server.
    # Use kwargs to set optional request parameters.
    authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
        # Enable offline access so that you can refresh an access token without
        # re-prompting the user for permission. Recommended for web server apps.
        access_type='offline',
        # Enable incremental authorization. Recommended as a best practice.
        include_granted_scopes='false')

    return authorization_url, state

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    authorization_url, state = redirect_user()
    return flask.redirect(authorization_url)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', title="Home Page")

@app.route('/oauth2callback')
def oauth2callback():
    flow = get_flow()
    auth_code = request.args['code']
    flow.fetch_token(code=auth_code)
    credentials = flow.credentials

    # Connect to the Gmail API
    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

    # request a list of all the messages
    result = service.users().messages().list(userId='me').execute()
    messages = result.get('messages')
    for msg in messages:
        print(msg['id'])

    # saving the credetials for later.
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(credentials.to_json())

    return "", 201

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Bind to PORT if defined, otherwise default to 5000.
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, ssl_context=context)
```

Comment: Each time i am getting this error i see just my http://localhost with different port numbers changing each time i re-run the code
it is not consistent altho i gave it only http://localhost:8000/

Comment: i did, but as i said when i give it the uri like you showed me, it just promps me with same uri but different port problem

Comment: Then instead of creating web app credentials create installed app credentials.    You cant use this code with a web app.   [CREATE A GOOGLE CREDENTIALS.JSON KEY FILE IN 17 SECONDS](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/BBgrgA96n-Q)

Comment: wow you are so amazing you helped me so much!! my app is gonna be a web server (like google chrome extention) do you have a guide for this kind of stuff? i am aiming to let a user login once and get his permissions to read his emails and then do things in the background for him using gmail API.

Comment: last line in my anwser check webserver flow.    I don't think I have written a quick start for it yet but it should like a good idea 

Comment: after reading it and trying it out im still running into problems
maybe you have really anything i can use to figure it out better or links to forums?

Comment: That's the only documentation I am aware of for web flow.   I will see if i can find time to get it working myself and do a video on it.

Comment: do i even need a "web-flow"? i remind you again, my goal is to make a user login into my app (website/ chrome extention) with google oauth2 and then use the permissions he gave me to do some work for him (e.g gmail stuff).

Comment: InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file <-- will launch the web browser on the machine its running on.  If its running on a web server then it will try to launch it on the web server.   Web flow will launch it on the clients web browser.  There is a big difference.    I'm trying to build a sample using flask.

Comment: thank you!
i dont need it as desktop app like the code snippet gave above, i do need it as server side. 
so you are correct i need to make it web app a flask example would be good, altho i currently use fastapi

Comment: Sadly I haven't been able to find any Web examples yet.    Working on my own but its slow going I'm surprised this isn't better documented

Comment: exactly, it is so hard to learn and figure it out alone without any documents.. hope to see a guide from you or code snippets

Comment: I am using Quickstart for Python as described here https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/python, what I notice is it and it's adding a un nesscery / at the end of the url and I can't add a URL with / at the end in Google Cloud Console. Please help.

Comment: Thank you, error details helped a lot. And noone in google, not even chatgpt, could suggest this.