# Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch because of trailing / in redirect uri from google standard Quickstart.py

Tags: python, google-api

I am using `developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/python` code as is.

Following is how my code looks like after I changed `flow.run_local_server` to `4200`

```
from __future__ import print_function

import datetime
import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.
    Prints the start and name of the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=4200)
            print(creds)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        # Call the Calendar API
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'  # 'Z' indicates UTC time
        print('Getting the upcoming 10 events')
        events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                              maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                              orderBy='startTime').execute()
        events = events_result.get('items', [])

        if not events:
            print('No upcoming events found.')
            return

        # Prints the start and name of the next 10 events
        for event in events:
            start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
            print(start, event['summary'])

    except HttpError as error:
        print('An error occurred: %s' % error)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Following is how my `credentials.json` looks like

```
{"web":{"client_id":"***","project_id":"***","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"***","redirect_uris":["http://localhost:4200"],"javascript_origins":["http://localhost:4200"]}}
```

---

After I run this code, I get following error

```
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy.

If you're the app developer, register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console.
Request details: redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/
Related developer documentation
```

Notice the trailing `/` in `Request details: redirect_uri=http://localhost:4200/` which is causing `Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch`

*How I know `/` is causing this error*. I tried following url without `/` or `%2F` in URL and it works fine.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=***&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar.readonly&state=***&access_type=offline
```

Looking forward for possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I modified following code

`creds = flow.run_local_server(port=4200)`

to

`creds = flow.run_local_server(redirect_uri_trailing_slash=False, port=4200)`

Now everything is working as expected.