# redirect_uri_mismatch while fetching accestoken and refreshtoken from react and django

Tags: reactjs, django, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api

i am trying to get accestoken and refreshtoken from google auth using django server ,

I am calling the api from frontend in reactjs , but i am getting the following error every time

> Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

my backend code looks like this ,

```
current_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = os.path.join(current_directory, 'client_secret.json')
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']
REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:3000/parent/our_information'
class GetAuthUrlView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        flow = Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
            CLIENT_SECRET_FILE,
            scopes=SCOPES,
            redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI
        )
        print(flow)
        auth_url, _ = flow.authorization_url(prompt='consent')
        return JsonResponse({'auth_url': auth_url})
class ExchangeCodeView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        code = request.GET.get('code')
        flow = Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
            CLIENT_SECRET_FILE,
            scopes=SCOPES,
            redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI
        )
        flow.fetch_token(code=code)
        credentials = flow.credentials
        access_token = credentials.token
        refresh_token = credentials.refresh_token
        return JsonResponse({'access_token': access_token, 'refresh_token': refresh_token})
```

redirect url in google console

[image]

frontend code of reactjs

```
 const [authUrl, setAuthUrl] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/email/get_auth_url')
      .then((response) => {
        setAuthUrl(response.data.auth_url);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, []);

  const handleSignIn = () => {
    window.location.href = authUrl;
  };

  const handleCallback = () => {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const code = urlParams.get('code');
    axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/email/exchangeToken/?code=${code}`)
      .then((response) => {
        const { access_token, refresh_token } = response.data;

        // Use access_token and refresh_token as needed
        console.log('Access Token:', access_token);
        console.log('Refresh Token:', refresh_token);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
   
    if (window.location.search.includes('code=')) {
      handleCallback();
    }
  }, []);
```

ps : i am newbie to django , if there any issue in code you can suggest edit

Comment: Try watching this.  https://youtu.be/QHz1Rs6lZHQ?si=qAyBHf9yDHSS926C

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Oauth2 - redirect\_uri\_mismatch 400](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75195100/google-oauth2-redirect-uri-mismatch-400)